# How to search for chess players by favourite opening

Tags: opening, database

Is there a convenient way to search for players by their opening? For example if I input 'Ruy Lopez' then it gives me a list of chess players, sorted by how many times they played Ruy Lopez in tournament.

I know that chess.com and 365chess has this feature, but they only provide 3 to 5 players per opening.

Answer (score 5):

I had created a python package called [pgnhelper](https://pypi.org/project/pgnhelper/) with [documentation](https://pgnhelper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which can be used to see what you would like to find.

Do not use a big pgn file as it will take more time. This is more useful for examining stats of a tournament. 5 or so tournament pgn files can be combined. Player names should be consistent.

#### Typical setup for windows 10

1. Intall python 3.7 or later from https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Install pgnhelper from command line.

```
pip install pgnhelper -U
```

3. Save the code below to ruylopez.py.

3.1 Download candidates games from https://theweekinchess.com/assets/files/pgn/wchcand22.pgn

3.2. Place the pgn file and ruylopez.py in the same directory.

4. Execute ruylopez.py from command line like an example below.

```
PS F:\pgnhelpter_test> python ruylopez.py
```

The ruylopez.py and wchcand22.pgn are in F:\pgnhelpter_test path where `pgnhelpter_test` is the folder or directory name.

#### Code

`ruylopez.py`

```
"""Show player names and number of games on the given opening name.

requirements:
  pip install pgnhelper -U
"""


import pgnhelper
import pandas as pd


# opening_name = 'Nimzo-Indian'
opening_name = 'Ruy Lopez'

pgnfn = 'wchcand22.pgn'
# https://theweekinchess.com/assets/files/pgn/wchcand22.pgn

df, players, israting = pgnhelper.record.get_pgn_data(pgnfn)

# print(df)
# df.to_csv("sample.csv", index=False)

openings = df.Opening.unique()
for o in openings:
    print(o)

data = {}
for p in players:
    data1 = {}
    for o in openings:
        dfw = df.loc[(df.Opening == o) & (df.White == p)]
        dfb = df.loc[(df.Opening == o) & (df.Black == p)]
        wcnt = len(dfw)
        bcnt = len(dfb)
        total = wcnt + bcnt
        data1.update({o: {'w': wcnt, 'b': bcnt, 'total': total}})

    data.update({p: {'data': data1}})

mydata = []
for p in players:
    mydata.append([opening_name, p,
                   data[p]['data'][opening_name]['w'],
                   data[p]['data'][opening_name]['b'],
                   data[p]['data'][opening_name]['total']])

mydf = pd.DataFrame(
    mydata,
    columns=['Opening', 'Player', 'Wgames', 'Bgames', 'Total'])

mydf = mydf.sort_values(by=['Total', 'Wgames'], ascending=[False, False])
print(mydf)

mydf.to_csv("ruylopez.csv", index=False)  # Save to csv file
```

#### Output

```
Sicilian defence
English opening
Ruy Lopez
QGD
Sicilian, Chekhover variation
Giuoco Pianissimo
Gruenfeld
Sicilian
Catalan
Nimzo-Indian
Catalan opening
Petrov
Reti
Four knights game
Four knights
English
Giuoco Piano
QGD semi-Slav
     Opening               Player  Wgames  Bgames  Total
2  Ruy Lopez     Nakamura, Hikaru       2       4      6
7  Ruy Lopez     Rapport, Richard       4       1      5
0  Ruy Lopez     Caruana, Fabiano       3       2      5
1  Ruy Lopez    Radjabov, Teimour       1       3      4
3  Ruy Lopez    Firouzja, Alireza       1       1      2
6  Ruy Lopez          Ding, Liren       0       2      2
4  Ruy Lopez  Nepomniachtchi, Ian       1       0      1
5  Ruy Lopez  Duda, Jan-Krzysztof       1       0      1
```

The code can be revised to show a column of score percentage. Can also be revised to show by ECO code.

Opening names in the game are printed in console due to:

```
openings = df.Opening.unique()
for o in openings:
    print(o)
```

Results are printed in console due to:

```
print(mydf)
```

csv file will be saved due to:

`mydf.to_csv("ruylopez.csv", index=False)  # Save to csv file`

You can change the opening name in  the code by changing below code:

```
opening_name = 'Ruy Lopez'
```

You can use different pgn file but be sure the game has Opening tag like below.

```
[Event "FIDE Candidates 2022"]
[Site "Madrid ESP"]
[Date "2022.06.17"]
[Round "1.3"]
[White "Caruana, Fabiano"]
[Black "Nakamura, Hikaru"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteTitle "GM"]
[BlackTitle "GM"]
[WhiteElo "2783"]
[BlackElo "2760"]
[ECO "C65"]
[Opening "Ruy Lopez"]
[Variation "Berlin defence"]
[WhiteFideId "2020009"]
[BlackFideId "2016192"]
[EventDate "2022.06.17"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 ...
```

There must be `Opening` tag.

```
[Opening "Ruy Lopez"]
```

#### Add eco

If the game in your pgn file has no Opening tag, you can use pgnhelper to add a tag.

Example from command line:

```
pgnhelper addeco --inpgnfn candidates_zurich_1953.pgn --outpgnfn eco_candidates_zurich_1953.pgn --inecopgnfn eco.pgn
```

See also the guide at https://pgnhelper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html.

The file `eco.pgn` is needed, you can [download](https://github.com/fsmosca/pgnhelper/tree/main/eco) it from github.

For example you can download pgn files from [weekinchess,](https://theweekinchess.com/) or from [pgnmentor.](https://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html#events)

Comment: This is excellent.  Great job breaking it down into accessible steps.  (+1)

Comment: Have you tried running with pypy? If most of your computation is pure python it could speed things up. But if it's pandas than you won't get any benefit.

Comment: I have not yet tried it with pypy. Will try it and compare the speed at some point when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure any of these solutions below provide exactly what you're looking for, but I think enough functionality is there to assist you in your goal. Though the second option is very similar to the [Chess365 functionality](https://www.365chess.com/opening.php?m=4&n=74&ms=e4.e5.d4&ns=3.5.74) you reference.

**Option 1: ChessGames.com General Search**
[ChessGames.com](https://www.chessgames.com/) allows searches by ECO code or opening.   For example, [here are the results](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=2021&playercomp=either&pid=&player=&pid2=&player2=&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=C45&eco=&result=) for games in the [Scotch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_Game) (ECOs C45–45) restricted to the year 2021. You can further restrict games by result (White wins, Black wins, draw, or "no draw"). You can parse the results easily enough.

**Option 2: ChessGames.com Opening Explorer**
ChessGames.com also has an opening explorer that will list around 6 practitioners of that opening ECO code (3 with the White pieces, and 3 with Black). For example, searching ECO code 65 ([Berlin Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Defence_(chess)) is 65–67) gives the following.

[image: Results from search]

**Option 3: ChessTempo.com Opening Explorer**
[ChessTempo.com](https://chesstempo.com/) has an [opening explorer](https://old.chesstempo.com/game-database.html) with some added filters including specifying a rating range. Again, you'd have to parse the results, but it seems relevant.

For example, I asked for all games with position after **1. e4 c5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. f4** ([Grand Prix Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicilian_Defence#Grand_Prix_Attack)) with both players rated 2700+.  It returns the following.

[image: Search results from ChessTempo]

Comment: Basically what I want is like your option 2, but with a longer list of players

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pgn-extract -e3 pgn-file-name` to split the pgn file by ECO codes of games, e.g., you will get files C60.pgn to C99.pgn for Ruy Lopez. You can then combine C60.pgn to C99.pgn to get a single Ruy Lopez file. You may also be able to export from scid vs pc games in a range of ECO codes. You can then simply browse the file in scid vs pc. Or extract games of a specific player (again using pgn-extract) and you will see how many games are extracted. Otherwise, you can use a "simple" bash (e.g., grep/sort/wc commands)/awk/sed/perl/python script to get player frequencies in a pgn file. (Sorry, I cannot write such a script quickly, but similar scripts may be available already.)

If you are more interested in a specific player, then extract first by player name and then get the statistics of their openings. (By the way, pgn-extract can add opening codes in a pgn file of they don't already exist.)

Or in scid vs pc filter games containing a given position, say, the position after 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5, and browse the filtered list.